# Facing some problem with global Variable in QT C++

Tags: sqlite, qt, global-variables, qt5

I have a login page and a welcome page (which open if user can bypass the login). In my login page 
there is a line edit for entering username. So, for holding the username I declared a global variable in
the login.h.
My login.h file:

```
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QString>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QMessageBox>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class login : public Qlogin
{
   Q_OBJECT

  public:
  login(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~login();

 private:
  Ui::login *ui;
     QString userDat; ///global variable
 };
 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I hold the username from the line edit in login.cpp like this.

My login.cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QSqlQueryModel>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QString>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QMessageBox>

login::login(QWidget *parent)
: Qlogin(parent)
, ui(new Ui::login)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

userDat = ui-> login_lineEdit ->text();


 }

  login::~login()
 {
  delete ui;
  }
```

I want to use the global variable userDat in my welcome.cpp file like this.

```
ui-> welcome_lineEdit->setText(userDat);
```

I've included all required header file in welcome.h and welcome.cpp. But it still says:
userDat is not declared in this scope.
please help

Comment: You have declared your userDat in class login and not globally. So your userDat is only available in login class scope. Move your userDat just right before #endif // MAINWINDOW_H

Comment: Thanks...but, it still says "multiple definition of userDat"

Comment: actually it is not good idea to use global vars in oop, better pack your data in some object and make class members static at least. Could look like that: class UserData
{
    public:
    static QString userName;
}
/* initialize this somewhere in source*/ QString UserData::userName ="";
UserData::userName = "some user name";

ui-> welcome_lineEdit->setText(UserData::userName);

Comment: I must have to retrieve the username form the lineEdit. in this case how should approach?

Comment: UserData::userName =  ui-> login_lineEdit ->text();

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I appreciate your help. But it says UserData::userName when I use it. I am a very beginner. Please help.

Comment: mayb you have brakets in this line? **ui-> welcome_lineEdit->setText(UserData::userName); **  should not look like ui-> welcome_lineEdit->setText("UserData::userName");

Comment: No bro.. It's okay as you have stated.

Comment: btw, where should I create the class? on login.h?

Comment: yes, in login.h just before class login ->    class UserData { public: static QString userName; }   class login : public ....

Comment: I did that... but still same

Comment: solved!!!!!! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Update from comments:

```
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QString>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QMessageBox>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class UserData { 
public: 
static QString userName; 
};

class login : public Qlogin
{
   Q_OBJECT

  public:
  login(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~login();

 private:
  Ui::login *ui;
 };
 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

in login.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QSqlQueryModel>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QString>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QMessageBox>

QString UserData::userName = "empty";

login::login(QWidget *parent)
: Qlogin(parent)
, ui(new Ui::login)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

UserData::userName = ui-> login_lineEdit ->text();


 }

  login::~login()
 {
  delete ui;
  }
```

and somethere in another place:

```
ui-> welcome_lineEdit->setText(UserData::userName);
```